# Triggering non-bubbling event jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to trigger a non-bubbling, non-cancellable event.  Is this possible?  Or do I always have to fire stopPropagation within event handlers.

I tried:

```
someobj.trigger({ type: 'some_event_type', bubbles: false, cancellable:false });
```

to no avail.  Seems like there should be a way to do it, but I haven't found it yet .....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [.triggerHandler](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/). It:

- do not bubble up the DOM hierarchy
- does not cause the default behavior of an event to occur
- affects only the first matched element

Answer (score 1):

Use event.stopPropogation to keep events from bubbling. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.stopPropagation

Comment: He knows this. He wants an alternative.

Comment: @undefined How do you know it’s a *he*?